# object cant access class properties

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a subclassed Button with a couple of properties

```
public class ZButton : Button
{    
    private string UIB = "I";
    public int _id_ { get; set; }
    public int rowIndex { get; set; }
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        Form frmNew = new Form(UIB);
        frmNew.ShowDialog();
        base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

I placed that button on the form and here is the code for that button in the form.

```
private void zButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
        _id_ = Convert.ToInt16( dataGridView1["id_city", rowIndex].Value.ToString());

    }
```

I cant access those properties (rowIndex) and (*id*) and compiler gives errors

```
The name 'rowIndex' does not exist in the current context
```

I am rather new to C# so I must be missing something obviuos.

Comment: totally bad design, custom control showing Form dialogs...

Comment: `sender` is the instance of the button for which click event handler is invoked. However it's `object`, so you have to cast: `((ZButton)sender).rowIndex = ...`. In winforms every control has name, so `zButton1.rowIndex = ...` would work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rowIndex` and `_id_` are properties of your `zButton`, they are not accesible directly in your form. So if you need to access them in the click event, you have to cast the `sender` to a `zButton` and access the properties of that instance.Something like this:

```
private void zButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    zButton but=(zButton)sender;     
    but.rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
    but._id_ = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1["id_city",but.rowIndex].Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If method zButton1_Click is a member of your form class, then it can directly access properties of the same class or its ancestor classes, not properties of aggregated objects like your button.

In order to access your button's properties, you should explicitly specify which object's properties you are trying to access. This means that if you want to access a property of an aggregated button zButton1, you should replace

```
dataGridView1["id_city", rowIndex]
```

with

```
dataGridView1["id_city", zButton1.rowIndex]
```

Answer (score 0):

cast your sender to button.

```
var button = sender as zButton;
    if (button != null)
    {
        button.rowIndex ...
        ...
    }
```